# Turtles do not change heading when reaching a specific patch

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to make the turtles change the heading after reaching the specific patches. But the code I wrote does not work. I created the turtles on the first patch, they will move to three directions (heading 90 heading 180 heading 270). In the direction of heading 180, part of the turtles expected to change their directions which are heading 90 and heading 270 again when the turtles reaching the specific patches, and another part of turtles still heading 180. I can not solve this problem. Any help will be appreciated. The code as below:

```
create-RiverVolumes ( Qin_average - Qin_randomizer )          

  [

    setxy 0 7

    set heading 90                                               

    set color blue - 2  

    set size 0.5                                                
  ]

create-RiverVolumes ( Qin_average - Qin_randomizer )          

  [

    setxy 0 7

    set heading 180                                           

    set color blue - 2                                          

    set size 0.5                                                

    set targets-list ( list patch 0 7 patch 0 5 patch 0 3 patch 0 1 patch 0 -2 patch 0 -4 patch 0 -6 patch 0 -8 )

   ]

ask RiverVolumes [

      face patch targets-list

      set heading 180

      set color blue - 2 

      set size 0.5

     ] 

ask RiverVolumes [

      face patch targets-list

      set heading 90

      set color blue - 2 

      set size 0.5 

     ]

create-RiverVolumes ( Qin_average - Qin_randomizer )

  [

    setxy 0 7

    set heading 270  

    set color blue - 2 

    set size 0.5   

  ]
```